# looking at a number in a tuple

Tags: python

Right now my function is not recoginizing my numbers in the list coeff as numbers. I am trying to pair up items from the two list and then sort them into a different list based on the value of mul. But everything is going into the negative list. How to i make sure it is considering mul as a number going into each if statement.

```
def balance_equation(species,coeff):
  data=zip(coeff,species)
  positive=[]
  negative=[]
  for (mul,el) in data:
    if mul<0:
        negative.append((el,mul))
    if mul>0:
        positive.append((el,mul))
```

Edit;
I ment to originally include this
balance_equation(['H2O','A2'],['6','-4'])

Comment: Could you post an example of values for `species` and `coeff` where it is not giving the expected output?

Comment: What is coeff? a list of numbers or strings?

Comment: You really need to post a sample input, the expected output, and the actual output so we can tell what's actually wrong with your code. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: There's your problem right there- `coeff` is a list of strings. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in the way you call it (`balance_equation(['H2O','A2'],['6','-4'])`), `mul` is a string rather than an int (`'6'` or `'-4'` rather than `6` or `-4`). Change your if statement to:

```
if int(mul)<0:
    negative.append((el,mul))
if int(mul)>0:
    positive.append((el,mul))
```

This converts `mul` to an integer before comparing it to 0.

Comment: I think he wants `int` rather than `float` here… but otherwise, doing the conversion on the `if` rather than on the whole list up front does seem a little clearer, at least for a beginner, so +1.

Comment: Figured out the same so I changed it to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first problem is that your function just returns `None`, just throwing away the two lists, so there's no way to even see whether it's doing the right thing.

If you fix that, you'll see that it *is* doing the right thing.

```
def balance_equation(species,coeff):
  data=zip(coeff,species)
  positive=[]
  negative=[]
  for (mul,el) in data:
    if mul<0:
        negative.append((el,mul))
    if mul>0:
        positive.append((el,mul))
  return negative, positive

>>> n, p = balance_equation(balance_equation('abcdef', range(-3,3))
>>> n
[('a', -3), ('b', -2), ('c', -1)]
>>> p
[('e', 1), ('f', 2)]
```

So, there are two possibilities:

1. Since the code you pasted is clearly not the actual code you're running, maybe you fixed the bug while rewriting it to post here.
2. You're not calling it with sensible inputs. For example, if you pass the parameters backward, since `species` is presumably a collection of strings, they'll all end up positive. Or, likewise, if you pass the coeffs as string representations of integers.

If it's the last problem—you're passing, say, `'abcdef', ['-3', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '3']`, and you want to deal with that within balance_equation instead of in the calling code, that's easy. Just add this line before the `zip`:

```
coeff = [int(x) for x in coeff]
```

Or change your `zip` to:

```
data = zip((int(x) for x in coeff), species)
```

By the way, I'm assuming you're on CPython 2. In Python 3, trying to compare a string to 0 will raise a `TypeError` instead of always returning `True`, while in other Python 2 implementations it might always return `False` instead of `True`…

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer, but there's also a simpler way of doing this in Python:

```
for (mul, el) in data:
    append_to = negative.append if mul < 0 else positive.append
    append_to(el)
```

Not sure what "should happen" to `0` though

Comment: This is briefer, but I don't really think it's simpler. Especially for a beginning programmer, it requires at least one more abstraction to think through, and seems less explicit. (For an experienced ocaml or haskell programmer just coming to python, on the other hand, sure.)

Comment: @abarnert criticism noted and appreciated. Was just throwing it in there "for a later date" perhaps.